# How do I hardcode my accesskey and secret access key in my .net source code?

Tags: c#, .net, aws-sdk

```
var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client();
string amiID = "ami;
string keyPairName = "aaaa";

// List<string> groups = new List<string>() ;
var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
{
    ImageId = amiID,
    InstanceType = "tttt",
    MinCount = 1,
    MaxCount = 1,
    KeyName = kkkk,
    SubnetId = "bbbb",
};
```

How do I hard-code my access key and secret access key ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCESS_KEY", "SECRET_KEY");
var ec2Config = new AmazonEC2Config() {
    // add configurations here, 
    // such as ServiceURL and RegionEndpoint
}
var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsCreds, ec2Config);
```

Learn more:

- [AmazonEC2Client Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_EC2_AmazonEC2Client.htm)
- [AmazonEC2Config Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_EC2_AmazonEC2Config.htm)

Anyway, hard-coding access key and secret key is not recommended. Please be really cautious, especially when you are going to share your code to a public repository.